# Is it really possible to access MS Access DB stored on an http server (windows or linux) from a winform app?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

As I can see here http://www.sqlstrings.com/MS-Access-connection-strings.htm

one could

Open connection to Access database located on a remote server:

"Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://Your-Remote-Server-IP; Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\App1\Your_Database_Name.mdb"

Did someone try this : access MS Access DB stored on a windows or http server from a winform app ?

Comment: It surely is possible; that doesn't mean it's a good idea though...

Comment: Yes, I am sure someone tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires the server to implement RDS for the MS Remote provider, which is [now deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811968.aspx).

Note that this worked via a service (the [OLE DB Remoting Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714365(VS.85).aspx)) and a custom protocol (RDS), so this will not work on a linux server.  It will work on a Windows server which has the MS Remote MDAC provider installed.  However, it is obsolete technology, and would be better implemented using a more modern technique.

Comment: What more modern means ? I can't see anything in so called "modern technology" (I guess ADO.NET / Webservices) which can give the equivalent of direct access as above.

Building a wall of complex layers is not suitable in the case of a simple application for one user with no required security. I don't consider that it is suitable architecture to be overly complicated for a need.

One should have the choice to select the best technology in each case. Sometimes I need architecture for 1 million users, sometimes I need "architecture" for 1 or 2 users.

Comment: Thanks for the link I mark your answer as right answer. I now remember about RDS. But Yes as said above SOAP is absolutely not equivalent to RDS in low scale need. Any user can build on RDS especially on MS Office, not from using SOAP.

Comment: Jet/ACE is not a very good data store for web-based applications, for one. It's perfectly good for lots of other purposes, but not good at all in that environment.